# Mockito doReturn does not work as expected

Tags: android, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to write some tests to validate a class that operates on files in the `Context#getFilesDir()` directory. I'm using `java.nio.file.Files#createTempDirectory` to create a directory to mock `getFilesDir()` output, then using Mockito to return it when `getFilesDir` is invoked.

Mockito seems to be creating a new temp directory every time even though I declare the result of `createTempDirectory` as a class variable and use it for my `spy`'d Context. This is causing tests to fail along with cleanup step because rather than one directory, I have six or seven which violates the required state for the class being tested.

Here's the link to my commit that shows the code I've written so far: https://github.com/msfjarvis/viscerion/commit/b1504d7206

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Mockito was doing its job properly. The problem here was my poor understanding of JUnit. The `@Before` annotation runs the method before *each* test, which was not what I wanted, since I was looking for the method to run once when the class was being tested. The correct annotation for that was `@BeforeClass` which solves the proble. Huge thanks to [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-before-beforeclass-beforeeach-beforeall) that explained the differences.